# Find End of Current Billing Period

Tags: c#, datetime, date-arithmetic

I've found an answer to this based on quarters but need to extend it to other billing periods. I've been going in circles and can't find a way out!

I'm writing a C# console app working with Dynamics 365 (Online) but I suppose it's more a maths question.

I have a company that has a renewal day set in the future, e.g. 01/02/2018 (1st Feb).

The billing period for a new order could be monthly, quarterly, biannual or annual.
I need to calculate the date of the end of the current billing period working backwards from the renewal date.

Here is what I have so far

```
DateTime contractRenewal = new DateTime(2018, 02, 01);
int MonthsInBillPeriod = getBillingPeriod() //returns 1 for monthly, 3 for quarterly etc.
int currQuarter = (DateTime.Now.Month - contractRenewal.Month) / MonthsInBillPeriod + 1;
int month = currQuarter * MonthsInBillPeriod + contractRenewal.Month;
while (month > 12)
    month = month - MonthsInBillPeriod;
renewal = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(month).Year, month, 1).AddDays(-1); //should return 30/09/2017 for monthly. 31/10/2017 for quarterly. 31/01/2018 for biannual and annual given contractRenewal date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it enough for you to handle months as such, without considering quarters? Like this:

```
DateTime tmpRenewal = contractRenewal;
while(tmpRenewal > DateTime.Now)
{
    tmpRenewal = tmpRenewal.AddMonths(-MonthsInBillPeriod);
}

// need to go one period forward, to the future from Now (as we are in the past right now)
DateTime renewal = tmpRenewal.AddMonths(MonthsInBillPeriod).AddDays(-1);
```